# map[byte]int and map[string]int have different memory usage

Tags: dictionary, go, memory-management

This question came from [a little simple problem from LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/description/).

**This question is not so related with the LeetCode problemm itself. But it's related with two approaches, which only has difference at the type of `map`, to solve this LeetCode problem.**

---

1. The first approach using `map[byte]int`:

```
func romanToInt(s string) int {
    m := map[byte]int{
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000,
    }
    result := 0
    length := len(s)
    last_element := length - 1
    for i := 0; i < last_element; i++ {
        current := m[s[i]]
        next := m[s[i+1]]
        if current < next {
            result -= current
        } else {
            result += current
        }
    }
    result += m[s[last_element]]
    return result
}
```

How it online judged by LeetCode:

```
✔ Accepted
  ✔ 3999/3999 cases passed (16 ms)
  ✔ Your runtime beats 100 % of golang submissions
  ✔ Your memory usage beats 22 % of golang submissions (3 MB)
```

---

2. The Second approach using `map[string]int`:

```
func romanToInt(s string) int {
    m := map[string]int{
        "I": 1,
        "V": 5,
        "X": 10,
        "L": 50,
        "C": 100,
        "D": 500,
        "M": 1000,
    }
    result := 0
    length := len(s)
    last_element := length - 1
    for i := 0; i < last_element; i++ {
        current := m[string(s[i])]
        next := m[string(s[i+1])]
        if current < next {
            result -= current
        } else {
            result += current
        }
    }
    result += m[string(s[last_element])]
    return result
}
```

How it online judged by LeetCode:

```
✔ Accepted
  ✔ 3999/3999 cases passed (16 ms)
  ✔ Your runtime beats 100 % of golang submissions
  ✔ Your memory usage beats 100 % of golang submissions (3 MB)
```

---

Some word to the online evaluation:
I had run this two versions more than 10 times in time interval 1 hour. And they achieve 22 % vs 100 % at `memory usage`.

**What I expected:**

I thought this first one using `map[byte]int` should be faster and memory-saver.

Why faster: 
In the second version, I have to cast the `rune` to `string` every time.
(But the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) tells me that is not a big difference.)

Why should be memory-saver: 
Because `byte` is more lighter than `string`.

---

**So final question:**

why there is a difference at the `memory usage`?
And why is my expectation wrong?

Comment: First, both of these results stated 16ms and 3MB, so there may actually be no real difference (you have to run a proper benchmark). Converting a to a string within a map index expression is a special case that is optimized way by the compiler. If there is a difference, string keys are the most common key type, they have the most optimized codepath. There's really no reason to make maps work well with `byte` keys when optimized code would probably use `[256]int{}` rather than a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benchmark your code, `romanToIntStr` and `romanToIntByt`. The difference between `romanToIntStr` and `romanToIntByt` is not significant. Your code, `romanToIntStr` and `romanToIntByt`, is not efficient. See `romanToIntArr`.

---

Output:

```
$ go test roman2int_test.go -bench=. -benchmem

BenchmarkRomanToIntStr-8    2725520   440 ns/op     0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkRomanToIntByt-8    2377992   499 ns/op     0 B/op   0 allocs/op

BenchmarkRomanToIntArr-8   25643797    42.3 ns/op   0 B/op   0 allocs/op
```

`roman2int_test.go`:

```
package main

import "testing"

func romanToIntStr(s string) int {
    m := map[string]int{
        "I": 1,
        "V": 5,
        "X": 10,
        "L": 50,
        "C": 100,
        "D": 500,
        "M": 1000,
    }
    result := 0
    length := len(s)
    last_element := length - 1
    for i := 0; i < last_element; i++ {
        current := m[string(s[i])]
        next := m[string(s[i+1])]
        if current < next {
            result -= current
        } else {
            result += current
        }
    }
    result += m[string(s[last_element])]
    return result
}

func romanToIntByt(s string) int {
    m := map[byte]int{
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000,
    }
    result := 0
    length := len(s)
    last_element := length - 1
    for i := 0; i < last_element; i++ {
        current := m[s[i]]
        next := m[s[i+1]]
        if current < next {
            result -= current
        } else {
            result += current
        }
    }
    result += m[s[last_element]]
    return result
}

func romanToIntArr(s string) int {
    m := [256]int{
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000,
    }
    result := 0
    last := len(s) - 1
    for i := 0; i < last; i++ {
        current := m[(s[i])]
        next := m[(s[i+1])]
        if current < next {
            result -= current
        } else {
            result += current
        }
    }
    result += m[(s[last])]
    return result
}

var bench1942 = "MCMXLII"

func BenchmarkRomanToIntStr(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        romanToIntStr(bench1942)
    }
}

func BenchmarkRomanToIntByt(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        romanToIntByt(bench1942)
    }
}

func BenchmarkRomanToIntArr(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        romanToIntArr(bench1942)
    }
}
```

Comment: BenchmarkRomanFast-8  200000000 7.42 ns/op


[code](https://pastebin.com/k8Ejzmvz)